# SELECT query check for something outside of database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query below and it works for the most part, until I just noticed it is causing a slight issue. Basically what the existing query does it select all the information from my 'home_comments' table and then matches the max id from the profile_img table and takes that image.

The issue I am running into is that not all of my users have profile images within this database. For default images, I use a static image. So, is there anyway I can check if the user has a profile_img and if not use this?

```
$default_profile_img = '<img class="home-profile-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';
```

Query:

```
$select_comments_sql = "
        SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
        FROM home_comments AS c
        INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                    FROM profile_img 
                    GROUP BY user_id) PI
          on PI.user_id = c.user_id
        INNER JOIN profile_img p
          on PI.user_id = p.user_id
         and PI.id = p.id
        ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

EDIT: updated SQL

```
$select_comments_sql = "
    //SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    SELECT c. *, PI.user_id, case when PI.img <> '' and PI.img is not null then PI.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    LEFT JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
";
```

Errors:

```
[27-Oct-2016 13:29:56 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
            SELECT c. *, PI.user_id, case when PI.img <> ' at line 1' in /home4//public_html/.com/account/ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php:36`
```

Comment: try change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN so you can select also the user that doesn't have a image.

Comment: How exactly would I do this?

Comment: Er, change the word 'inner' to 'left'

Comment: @Strawberry Doing that is now making the comment show up, except for the user's default image.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you. I never knew this was recommended. I have only posted 2-3 SQL questions on here as I do not do too much with it. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: However, the image that I need to show is not in the database, so essentially it is working, I just need the image to be put in the query somehow for this with missing profile_img rows.

Comment: So, I am still using my original query, except changed the inner's to left. Then I tried to use the case provided `SELECT c. *, p.user_id, case when p.img <> '' and p.img is not null then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img` , but it is breaking the code.

Comment: Unknown column 'p.user_id' in 'field list' - i think we had better see a list of the columns in each table...

Comment: @WEBjuju Sorry, I posted the error from my retrieving php after a new comment was inserted. I just updated that (the query is the same) and it now throws the updated error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case statement:

```
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, case when p.img <> '' and p.img is not null then p.img else 'my-default.png' end img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Comment: No luck with this.

Comment: Oh, what did you get back?

Comment: It isn't showing any errors within the error logs or displaying on the page. I have error reporting on.

Comment: I think the LEFT JOIN problem is what is going on: select stuff from home_comments c LEFT JOIN profile_img PI on c.user_id = PI.user_id should do it...do they have multiple profile images?

Comment: Yes, they have multiple profile images and I am only trying to display the last one entered, ie: max(id).

Comment: So, just change INNER to LEFT?

Comment: So, I am still using my original query, except changed the inner's to left. Then I tried to use your case ` SELECT c. *, p.user_id, case when p.img <> '' and p.img is not null then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img` , but it is breaking the code.

Comment: can you give me the error the query gives?  i cannot help with the phrase "breaks the code"

Comment: I removed my commented code from the query and now the console produces this error: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PI.img' in 'field list'' in `

Comment: I figured it out. I changed `PI.img` to `p.img`, while leaving `PI.user_id`. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: awesome!  great work!  i know it feels good to figure it out!  congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, I assume you use `mysqli` and `$row` returns associative array.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_comments_sql);
if(!empty($row['profile_image_field_name'])){
    $default_profile_img = '<img class="home-profile-pic" src="profile_images/'.$row['profile_image_feild_name'].'">';
}else{
    $default_profile_img = '<img class="home-profile-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: Using PDO. Any difference?

Comment: I have already tried this with no luck, so it lead me to believe the query needed changed. `$html .= sprintf(
      '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src="%s">',
      empty($row['img']) ? 'profile_images/default.jpg' : $row['img']
     );`